# CORS response to preflight request when endpoint takes argument

Tags: asp.net, cors, asp.net-web-api2

i have an Angular2 application and a ASP.NET web api 2 with cors enabled globally: 
[image]

and a controller with a post, taking a login model (email and password as strings)[image]

and the request from client:
[image]

If i leave the parameter empty, i have no problem calling it from my frontend, but if i leave it to require the loginmodel, i get the following:
[image]
and the request: 
[image]

Can someone tell how this can be? And not at least how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Cannot explain this, but it worked.
I removed:

```
          var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
          config.EnableCors(cors);
```

From my WebApiConfig and instead added the following to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <!-- This enables your CORS Requests to be accepted. -->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

The reason why i did not do this from the beginnig was that my Web api 2 did not have the system.webserver, it has an system.web, and i was not aware i could have both. If anyone can bring some sense to this, please do